# Calling nested recyclerview adapter to get data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make workouts log app. I designed adding new workout as shown on pic below:

[NewWorkoutActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utIVm.jpg)

In AddWorkoutActivity there is a recyclerview of exercises with ExercisesListAdapter. 
Inside this recyclerview is another recyclerview of sets (no., weight, reps) with SetsListAdapter.

What I'm trying to do is to collect the data when user clicks on SAVE button.
The problem I struggle is, that I don't know how to call SetsListAdapter from ExercisesListAdapter class.

NewWorkoutActivity:

```
public class NewWorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<ExerciseItem> exercises;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new);

    final ExercisesListAdapter exercisesListAdapter = new ExercisesListAdapter(this);
    exercisesRecyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesListAdapter);
    exercisesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    addExerciseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<ExerciseSetItem> esi = new ArrayList<>();
            exercisesListAdapter.addExercise(new ExerciseItem("New Exercise", esi));
        }
    });
}
```

ExercisesListAdapter:

```
public class ExercisesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExercisesListAdapter.exerciseViewHolder> {

class exerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView exerciseTextView;
    private final RecyclerView setsRecyclerView;
    private final Button addSetButton;

    private exerciseViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        exerciseTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_name_text_view);
        setsRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.sets_recycler_view);
        addSetButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_set_button);
    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<ExerciseItem> mExercises;

ExercisesListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public exerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_exercise_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new exerciseViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final exerciseViewHolder exerciseViewHolder, int i) {

    // Attach sets to recycler view
    final SetsListAdapter exerciseSetsAdapter =
            new SetsListAdapter(exerciseViewHolder.addSetButton.getContext());

    exerciseViewHolder.setsRecyclerView.setAdapter(exerciseSetsAdapter);
    exerciseViewHolder.setsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(exerciseViewHolder.addSetButton.getContext()));


    if(mExercises != null) {
        ExerciseItem exercise = mExercises.get(i);
        exerciseViewHolder.exerciseTextView.setText(exercise.name);
    }

    exerciseViewHolder.addSetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mExercises.get(exerciseViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).sets.
                    add(new ExerciseSetItem(0,0));
            exerciseSetsAdapter.setSets(mExercises.
                    get(exerciseViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).sets);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mExercises != null)
        return mExercises.size();
    else return 0;
}

public void setExercises(List<ExerciseItem> exercises) {
    mExercises = exercises;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

SetListAdapter:

```
public class SetsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetsListAdapter.exerciseSetViewHolder>  {

class exerciseSetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView setTextView;
    private final EditText weightEditText;
    private final EditText repsEditText;

    private exerciseSetViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        setTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_set_text_view);
        weightEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_set_weight_edit_text);
        repsEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_set_reps_edit_text);
    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<ExerciseSetItem> mSets;

SetsListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public exerciseSetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_set_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new exerciseSetViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull exerciseSetViewHolder workoutViewHolder, int i) {

    if(mSets!= null) {
        ExerciseSetItem item = mSets.get(i);
        workoutViewHolder.setTextView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        workoutViewHolder.weightEditText.setText(String.valueOf(item.weight));
        workoutViewHolder.repsEditText.setText(String.valueOf(item.reps));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mSets != null)
        return mSets.size();
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public void setSets(List<ExerciseSetItem> sets) {
    mSets = sets;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<ExerciseSetItem> getSets() {
    return mSets;
}
```

I had idea to collect every adapter in a list, but it doesn't seems good to me.

Comment: If I understood, you want to transfer data from one adapter to another?

Comment: Exactly. From SetsListAdapter I want to send list of sets (with reps and weights) to ExercisesListAdapter and next collect the data in NewWorkoutActivity to save it to database.

Comment: But for now I'm going to refactor it and try to use MVVM pattern. It would be better way to get it.

Comment: Not very efficient, but you can make a getter in SetsListAdapter to get the items in the Activity and pass that list to the ExercisesListAdapter.